# Monitoring remote docker container with prometheus

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers, prometheus, health-monitoring

I have a server-A in which i have installed prometheus, alertmanager, grafana, pushgateway, cadvisor, node_exporter, caddy now i want to monitor docker container which is created in server-B. I have searched and found some solutions but non of them working correctly. Anybody know the solution for it plz guide

Comment: It's better if you describe your networking setup more thoroughly. How do use expose ports on the docker container? What orchestration tool do you use - kubernetes? docker-compose?

Comment: The ports are run with main server IP. I am using docker-compose

Comment: Prometheus monitoring resourse of server-A but i need to monitor resourse of server-B also in prometheus